# Aggregate query not working:Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have an query for aggrigate as below,

```
ResearchPapers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: params
 },
 {
$group: {
  _id: "$pmid"
},
"Title": {
  "$first": "$Title"
},
"url": {
  "$first": "$url"
},
"year": {
  "$first": "$year"
},
"month": {
  "$first": "$month"
},
"day": {
  "$first": "$day"
}
},
 {
$sort: {
  year: -1,
  month: -1,
  date: -1
  }  }]).exec(function(cerr, records){
    if(cerr){
     return console.log(cerr);
   }
 });
```

When I execute my query ,I am getting the error as `

```
   Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators
```

I am unable to find the sol and I am new to node js and mongoose.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: can you please share what exactly you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your braces are incorrect, and you are terminating the $group object to early. Your third sort predicate is also referencing a field that does not exist. Here is the corrected pipeline:

```
ResearchPapers
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: params
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$pmid",
      "Title": {
        "$first": "$Title"
      },
      "url": {
        "$first": "$url"
      },
      "year": {
        "$first": "$year"
      },
      "month": {
        "$first": "$month"
      },
      "day": {
        "$first": "$day"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      year: -1,
      month: -1,
      day: -1
    }
  }
]).exec(function(cerr, records) {
  if (cerr) {
    return console.log(cerr);
  }
});
```